# Decimales en mvc

Tags: asp.net, mvc, aplicación-web

Que tal. Estoy desarollando una aplicacion web en Mvc, y es una calculadora medica, donde el usuario ingresa ciertos valores, se hace la cuenta, y devuelve un valor. En los casos donde la entrada tiene que ser con decimales, me tira el siguiente error:

```
El diccionario de parámetros contiene una entrada NULL para el parámetro 'globroj' del tipo que no acepta valores NULL 'System.Decimal' del método 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CalcularHematocritos(System.Decimal, System.Decimal)' en 'Griersonmvc.Controllers.HomeController'. Un parámetro opcional debe ser un tipo de referencia, un tipo que acepte valores NULL o debe declararse como parámetro opcional.Nombre del parámetro: parameters
```

Con el resto de numeros va perfecto. probe poniendo en vez de la coma el punto en el numero, pero tampoco. Les dejo el formulario y el controlador de este caso..

gracias!

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CalcularHematocritos(decimal globroj, decimal volsan)
    {
     decimal resultadoh = (globroj / volsan)*100;

        ViewBag.Resultadoh = resultadoh;
        return View("resultadoh");

    }
```

Y el HTML es este

```
 <form action="@Url.Action("CalcularHematocritos" , "Home")" method="post">
                                <div>

                                    <label for="number">
                                        <span class="required">Volumen de Globulos Rojos *</span>
                                        <input type="number" step="0.01"  id="globroj" name="globroj" value="" placeholder="Vol. Glob. Roj." required="required" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus" />
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                                <div>
                                    <label for="number">
                                        <span class="required">Volumen Sangre</span>
                                        <input type="number" step="0.01"  id="volsan" name="volsan" value="" placeholder="Vol. San." tabindex="2" required="required" />
                                    </label>

                                    <div>
                                        <button name="submit" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit">Calcular </button>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </article>
```

Comment: es que la idea es que no haya null. Este error me sucede cuando pongo un valor decimal, cuando dejo vacio en cambio, me avisa que si o si debo poner un valor.

Answer (score 1):

El problema se debe a que estás ejecutando una petición de tipo `POST` y las variables las recibes como parámetros en el Controller, si fuera una petición `GET` no tendrías ningún problema. El punto aquí es que los datos enviados desde el formulario viajan en el cuerpo de la petición y solo tendrías que agregarles el atributo `[FromBody]` para que pudieras recibirlos como tú esperas.

Código del Controller:

```
using System.Web.Http;
```

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalcularHematocritos([FromBody]decimal globroj, [FromBody]decimal volsan)
{
    ViewBag.Resultado = (globroj / volsan) * 100;
    return View();
}
```

Código del View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Calcular Hematocritos";
}

<h2>El resultado del cálculo es: @ViewBag.Resultado</h2>
```

Nota: si te marca algún error al momento de agregar el atributo `[FromBody]`, tienes que instalar la librería desde NutGet Package Console:

1. Menú <kbd>Tools</kbd> `-->` <kbd>NutGet Package Manager</kbd> `-->` <kbd>NutGet Package Console</kbd>
2. Pegar `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core -Version 5.2.3` y dar la tecla <kbd>Enter</kbd>